# How can web and error events be logged to Splunk using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, splunk

I've found plenty of documentation on how to perform Splunk searches from within Node.js (thanks in chief to the Splunk javascript SDK documentation).

However, that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I am hoping to use Splunk as my logging/monitoring/analytics solution for a site which is driven by node.js. I need to be able to log different types of events (login errors, page requests/responses, etc) for Splunk to index and make usable.

How can this be accomplished? Is it part of the SDK (or the API itself) that I'm just overlooking?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston). This is a framework similar to Log4Net or Log4J which provides variable log levels and transport options.

They do not appear to have a "transport" / plug-in for Splunk, but they have several others including the relatively similar Loggly. They also have instructions on rolling your own, so it looks like a good place to start.

Comment: This looks like it might be the most elegant approach to what I'm trying to accomplish, and it also leads to some alternative services. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

At our recent Splunk Conference we held a Hackathon and one of the winners actually developed a Splunk transport for Winston. [You can grab it from github](https://github.com/erichelgeson/winston-splunk).